# Apache2 server unable to run locally in browser

Tags: apache2, php

I was trying to install laravel 5.6 , at mean time my php version was 5 so to install laravel ubuntu suggested me to upgrade my php version so i upgrade my php 5 to 5.6. so when i upgrade php. when i was suppose to upgrade php to 5.6 my appache server did not run locally with some error message:

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

So now what shall i do to run my php version? i am not suppose to fix the problem which has arise recently?

Comment: I suppose line 219 of your apache2.conf reads something like `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`, and there is a broken link `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf` to a non-existent file. If this is not the case, please post the content of line 219 of your apache2.conf.

Comment: ya this is the case i have two file ... as you mention so what shall do to fix error??

Comment: To fix this error you have to remove the broken links. Have a look in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`if there are any configuration files you need, and then create softlinks to them as `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/<name-of-conffile> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. Or use `a2dissite` and `a2ensite` instead, if available; this will do this for you (please read the man page!).  I cannot help which site configuration files you need, this depends on your installation.

Comment: thank ya there was a broken file. so i fix it by deleting the broken file which was in sites-enabled.